# "Manual User Signing & Encryption Certificates Enrollment" profile in Dogtag CA doesn't work with fresh installation

Tags: ssl-certificate, fedora, certificate-authority, pki

After Dogtag 10 installation (step by step by [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3eElJAz7lU)) when I try to submit request "Manual User Signing & Encryption Certificates Enrollment"(3rd option) to CA by CA end-entity(end user web interface) I get following error:

> Sorry, your request is not submitted. The reason is "Unknown Certificate Request Type "

I don't touch any dogtag certification profiles.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681)  and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. - Please improve your question or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed. - For instance check the log files on your server and use something like openssl to inspect your  certificate signing request  e.g. `openssl req -in mycsr.csr -noout -text`

Comment: Thanks for edit @HBruijn .I don't have access do .csr request becouse it's created by browser.